# javascript date issue

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Why is it that in javascript I create a new date object `mydate = new Date('2011-10-03');` and it prints as October 2nd? `Sun Oct 02 2011 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)`

If I set the date to be October 3rd shoudn't I get a 3 when I call `mydate.getDate();`?

What I am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your date is off by one because it's being parsed in UTC time and you're displaying it in mountain time (I assume your local time).  This is per ECMA spec.

See section 15.9.3.3 of the Javascript specification here:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: Is there a way to specify that I want it parsed in local time (wherever the users browser happens to be)?

Comment: I think so, maybe like: var myDate = new Date('October 3, 2011 EST');

Comment: Oh, you need to parse in the browser's configured timezone.  Yeah that might get tricky heh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
mydate = new Date('2011/10/03');
```

Comment: That is great! But why is that? By simply changing the date format string it works like expected?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is setting the date to `2011-10-03` and the time to `00:00:01` for UTC.

And the print is converting that date object to your local time